# Are there negative implications to referencing many assemblies?

Tags: c#

What are the negative implications of referencing many assemblies? I have noticed ReSharper has the ability to "Remove Unused References" (though, sometimes it's wrong, such as when assemblies that depend on a reference are loaded at runtime via Ninject), but is there any benefit besides making the project look a little cleaner? Will the resulting assembly take use less memory at runtime? Perhaps the compiler is smart enough to notice a reference is unused?

Comment: Why are you adding references you don't need in the first place?

Comment: If you're deploying to Silverlight, then you'll have unnecessary assemblies being transferred to clients. Generally speaking, I try to minimize the project references to what is required: helps avoiding circular references that don't exist, helps minimize dependencies, and gives me a really quick/accurate look as to what each project depends on.

Comment: @Servy I know VS adds a bunch of typical System assemblies (System.Xml, System.Windows, System.Core, etc.) which often times can be removed. But in general, I agree: there's no point in manually _adding_ assembly references until you need them (and then you should try to be vigilant to remove them when refactoring out dependencies)

Comment: Assembly references just happen over time, especially in collaborative projects. Between NuGet and just adding references that were once necessary, but ended up not-necessary before checking in the final result for a change (so that the visual diff appears as if they were required) results in more references than absolutely required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is smart enough to ignore any unused references.

However, there would be a performance impact with many assemblies referenced in Visual Studio Intellisense.

From [C# Team's FAQ Blog on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/10/20/245411.aspx)

> Given that the .NET platform encourages binary reuse of types, it is commonplace to set references to external assemblies using the Visual Studio .NET Add Reference dialog box. Many programmers (especially those of the C(++) ilk) fear that adding unnecessary external references can result in a bit of 'code bloat'. Nothing could be further from the truth. When you add assembly references or make use of the 'using' keyword, csc.exe will ignore any assembly which you have not actually made use of in your code.

Comment: Could you provide a reference (to the first part- I'll take your word for it on intellisense impact)?

Comment: @Sam.Rueby See - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/10/20/245411.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Every assembly reference is a dependency that increases coupling within a system. The biggest impact in my experience to having too many references is it indicates poorly enforced system design and can be indicative of a system on its way to becoming a [big ball of mud](http://www.laputan.org/mud/).